# Search Function in Binary Search Tree causes seg fault

Tags: c, string, search, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I've been trying to get this BST working for the last few days, and I am getting stuck on the search function. The logic seems to be correct (unless I'm missing very important details) but there still is something wrong with the code. Could it be because I am dealing with strings? Anyways, here is some code:

**EDIT:** I've pinpointed somewhere that seems to be going wrong. It turns out that my root is always null. I placed a *printf* to test if the NULL-case were true, and it always printed true. I've added my tree initialization at the bottom of this question.

The (Updated) Search Function:

```
//Thank you, M Oehm
node* search(node * tree, char *key)
{
    /* char *key is user input */
    int cmp;

    if(tree == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    cmp = strcmp(key, tree->key);   
    if(cmp < 0) return search(tree->left, key);   
    if(cmp > 0) return search(tree->right, key);
    return tree;
}
```

Implementation in main function:

```
printf("Enter a string to search the tree with: ");
fgets(findNode, MAX_WORD, stdin);
findString = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(findNode)+1);
strcpy(findString,findNode);
printf("findString: %s\n", findString);
searched = search(&root, findString);
if(searched == NULL) {
    printf("No_such_key\n");
    free(findString);
    }
else {
    printNode(searched);
    free(findString);
    }
break;
```

Tree Initialization (via file parsing):

```
 /* Loop through each line in the file*/
 while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
     tempToken = strtok(buffer, " \n");
     while(tempToken != NULL) {
         /* Assign default values */
         curr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
         curr->left = curr->right = NULL;
         curr->key = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(tempToken)+1); /* +1 for '\0' */
         strcpy(curr->key, tempToken);
         curr->frequency = 1;           
         /* Insert node into tree */
         insert(&root, curr);
         /* Get next token */
         tempToken = strtok(NULL, " \n");
     }
 }
 /* Test insertion worked; close file */
 print_inorder(root);
 fclose(file);
```

Insertion Function:

```
void insert(node ** tree, node * item)
{
    /* If no root, item is root */
    if(!(*tree)) {
        *tree = item;
        return;
    }
    /* If item value is less than node in tree, assign to left */
    if(strcmp(item->key,(*tree)->key) < 0) {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, item);
    }
    else if(strcmp(item->key,(*tree)->key) > 0) {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, item);
    }
    else if(strcmp(item->key,(*tree)->key) == 0) {
        (*tree)->frequency++;
    }
}
```

The print function shows me that the insertion works properly.

Comment: You should test for `if (*tree == NULL)` at the beginning to catch the empty sub-tree case. Why are you working with double pointers here anyway? Your function doesn't modify the tree.

Comment: I think you should ensure that the construction of the tree is correct - unit testing?

Comment: Am I not searching the whole tree? Or would I just have to work with one node: the root. And from there I can traverse down to the root's children and so on?

Comment: That is correct, the search function just needs to get the Root node and the string value to search.

Comment: Can you please the code for creating this BST? How are you creating that "root" object?

Comment: You could also write this as a non-recursive function. When you use recursion as in your code, you must pass the found node back, so the recursive calls should read `return search(...)`. Your function will return 0, unless the matched node is the root node.

Comment: Alright I've added my initialization and my insert function. Perhaps this will help clear the air.

Comment: Look at the first `if` in `insert` and in `search`. You've got the check right in `insert`, but not in `search`.

Comment: My apologies. I had changed the search function so the first parameter is: **node * root**, instead of having the double pointer, like in the insert function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code: You don't check whetehr the root node, to which you pass a pointer, is null and you don't return the results from the recursive functions.

Your function doesn't modify the tree, so you don't have to pass a pointer to the nodes. That method is useful for functions that modify the tree, e.g. for inserting or deleting nodes. Your function shoul pass a pointer to the root node. That also signals to the user that the tree won't be modified.

So here's a corrected version:

```
node* search(node *tree, const char *key)
{
    int cmp;

    if (tree == NULL) return NULL;

    cmp = strcmp(key, tree->key);

    if (cmp < 0) return search(tree->left, key);
    if (cmp > 0) return search(tree->right, key);
    return tree;
}
```

That version must be called like this:

```
node *hit = search(tree, "bingo!");
```

Note that this function does the string comparison only once and saves the result in a temporary variable. Your code calls `strcmp` up to three times.

You don't have to use recursion here. It's even a bit wasteful, because you have to percolate the answer up the first call. Recursion is useful when each step has to maintain a state, which you can represent as local variables. Here, you just change the input `node`.

Here's a non-recursive variant of the `search` function:

```
node* search(node *tree, const char *key)
{
    while (tree) {
        int cmp = strcmp(key, tree->key);

        if (cmp == 0) return tree;
        tree = (cmp < 0) ? tree->left : tree->right;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the passing pointers confusion. That makes a lot more sense. Now, I fixed up my search function and there are no seg faults but I keep getting a "No_such_key", which is my message when the returned node is NULL. The **char *key** is user input; could this be the problem? Am I forgetting to add a null terminator or possibly forget to remove an extra unwanted character in this string?

Comment: You remove a possible trailing new-line with `strtok` in the code that inserts the string, but you don't do that for the string you serach the tree with.

Comment: Ahhh this is one of those face palm moments. It works now! Thank you so much, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

```
search(&(*tree)->left, key);
```

Should be:

```
return search(&(*tree)->left, key);
```

Same for the right case.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your function to something like this.

```
node* search(node * tree, char * key)
{
    if(tree == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if(strcmp(key,tree->key) < 0) {
        return search(tree->left, key);
    }

    else if(strcmp(key,tree->key) > 0) {
        return search(tree->right, key);
    }


    printf("Success!\n");
    return tree;

}
```

A simple node* would suffice for your problem. No need for double pointers.